# Is there a way to avoid the usage of `tokio::select!` macro?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm using the below code (from [here](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/graceful-shutdown/src/main.rs)) to handle graceful shutdown:

```rust
use tokio::signal;

pub async fn shutdown_signal() {
    let ctrl_c = async {
        signal::ctrl_c()
            .await
            .expect("failed to install Ctrl+C handler");
    };

    #[cfg(unix)]
    let terminate = async {
        signal::unix::signal(signal::unix::SignalKind::terminate())
            .expect("failed to install signal handler")
            .recv()
            .await;
    };

    #[cfg(not(unix))]
    let terminate = std::future::pending::<()>();

    tokio::select! {
        _ = ctrl_c => {},
        _ = terminate => {},
    }

    tracing::info!("signal received, starting graceful shutdown...");
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the usage of `tokio::select!` macro?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Because I would like to remove the `macros` feature in my Cargo.toml (I'm cleaning it very hard to reduce boilerplate).

Comment: I would say don't bother.

Comment: This is the only tokio macro I'm using in the code and I think this is avoidable.

Comment: Do you have a dependency on `futures`?

Comment: Yep I have `futures = { version = "0.3.26", default-features = false }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`futures`'s `select()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.select.html):

```rust
use tokio::signal;

pub async fn shutdown_signal() {
    let ctrl_c = async {
        signal::ctrl_c()
            .await
            .expect("failed to install Ctrl+C handler");
    };

    #[cfg(unix)]
    let terminate = async {
        signal::unix::signal(signal::unix::SignalKind::terminate())
            .expect("failed to install signal handler")
            .recv()
            .await;
    };

    #[cfg(not(unix))]
    let terminate = std::future::pending::<()>();
    
    tokio::pin!(ctrl_c, terminate);

    futures::future::select(ctrl_c, terminate).await;

    tracing::info!("signal received, starting graceful shutdown...");
}
```

Comment: With this (and without macros feature) I'm having the errror: `#[tokio::main]
  |          ^^^^ could not find main in tokio`. I think I cannot remove macros feature.

Comment: @FredHors If you are using `tokio::main`, this this is not the only usage of tokio's macros you have. This answer is correct nevertheless :) But if you're using `tokio::main`, you have a binary and not a library, and in this case, you have no reason to minimize features - you can happily have `full` turned on.